# で to mean "and"

Tags: particle-で

There are various ways to say and in japanese but what I am interested in is で to mean "and". Can someone explain the usage of で. Example sentence:

> 貴方の背が高い**で**顔もかっこい**で**憧れちゃう　－　You are tall **and** handsome **and** i end up yearning to be you
>
> 子猫ちょっとかわいそう**で**寂しそう　－ The kitten looks pitiful **and** lonely

Comment: Did you make up that first example?  If not, where is it from?

Comment: @snailcar Yes, I made it up. I realised that te-form can be used. But I believe I heard people using it like this before

Answer (score 2):

Do you know how you can use the te-form of verbs to mean 'and'?
For example,

> 食堂に行って、昼ご飯を食べて、昼寝をする。
>
> I will go to cafeteria, eat lunch, and take a nap.

で is just the te-form of です.

Comment: Yes, I know te-form i used. So that first sentence in my question is utter garbage and no one uses it like that?

Comment: I won't comment on whether someone would say that or not. But, I'd normally expect …高くて顔もかっこよくて… (just sounds more natural)